# Can I use Scala List with Slick (Play)?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm trying to store a List of integers here is what I am doing:

**MODEL**

```
case class Score(
  scoresPerTime: List[Int]
)

object Scores extends Table[Score]("SCORES"){
   def scorePerTime = column[List[Int]]("SCORE_PER_TIME")
   //...more code
}
```

**Controller**

```
val form = Form(
  Map(
    "scoresPerTime" -> list(number)
  )(Score.apply)(Score.unapply)
)
```

I get one compilation **error**:

```
.... could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[List[Int]][error]   def scorePerTime = column[List[Int]]("SCORE_PER_TIME")
```

How can I fix this to enter a list? or maybe try another option like a tuple, enum...

Comment: First of all: what you want is probably possible without a problem. Just to be sure: I assume that you want to save this `List[Int]` to a single table column, say, as a comma-separated string or similar. Is that correct? Or do you want Slick to generate a new table with all the `List`'s items referenced there for you?

Comment: @Carsten I was thinking of each Int in the List would be inserted in its own row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by defining a type mapper from let's say List[Int] to String and vice-versa.

One possibility:

```
implicit def date2dateTime = MappedTypeMapper.base[List[Int], String](
  list => list mkString ",",
  str => (str split "," map Integer.parseInt).toList
)
```

I say it's a possibility 'cause I haven't tested. Not sure the fact it's returning a list will disrupt Slick. One place where it can be ambiguous are aggregate queries, where you'd want to count the number of `,` and not do a `count(field)` (which will obviously be one).

But this is completely non-relation. The relational way would be to have a new table with two fields, one foreign key referring one line at table `SCORES` and another field with one `SCORE_PER_TIME`. The foreign key should be a non-unique index so searches are fast. And slick handles this pretty well.